# Issue with JQuery Post

Tags: jquery

I've following code

```
$(".momentoCommentArea").on('keypress',function(event) {
    console.log(event.which); //mypublicpost.js:42
    if (event.keyCode == 13) { //enterkey //mypublicpost.js:43
        var message = $(".momentoCommentArea").val(); //mypublicpost.js:44
        //mypublicpost.js:44
        $.post('momento/newComment',  //mypublicpost.js:46
                    {'picaid':currentFid,'msg':message},
                    function(data){
                var tComment=$("<div></div>").addClass('momento-comment');
                var imgUrl=$("#siddlb-comments").children(".momento-comment").children('.momento-comment-img').children('img').attr('src');
                $("<div></div>").addClass('momento-comment-img').html('<img src="'+imgUrl+'" width="40" height="40" />').appendTo(tComment);
                $("<div></div>").addClass('momento-comment-comment').html("<b>"+$("#membername").html()+"</b><br/>"+message).appendTo(tComment);
                $("<div></div>").addClass('momento-comment-date').html('This seccion').appendTo(tComment);
                $("#momento-comments > div.momento-comment:first").before(tComment);
        });
    }
});
```

Running the code (Enter text in textarea and press enter) generates following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-1.7.2.js:7740
  jQuery.extend.param.add jquery-1.7.2.js:7740
  buildParams jquery-1.7.2.js:7797
  buildParams jquery-1.7.2.js:7792
  buildParams jquery-1.7.2.js:7792
  buildParams jquery-1.7.2.js:7792
  buildParams jquery-1.7.2.js:7792
  buildParams jquery-1.7.2.js:7792
  buildParams jquery-1.7.2.js:7792
  jQuery.extend.param jquery-1.7.2.js:7760
  jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.7.2.js:7606
  jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery-1.7.2.js:7245
  (anonymous function) mypublicpost.js:45  //EDIT: line 45 is $.post line
  jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.js:3332
  jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

Can someone please suggest what that error mean and how should I approach to fix that error?

**Edit**

Screenshot of dev tool in chrome

[image]

Comment: `keyCode` is not cross-browser you can use `which` instead.

Comment: changed `event.keyCode` to `event.which` but no change. getting same error.

Comment: Can you check in your developer tools what the post request gets back?

Comment: @AndersHolmström Ahh its not even posting. Editing question with screenshot

Comment: What row in your js file is row 46?

Comment: @AndersHolmström Edited code with line numbers as comment in the end. Line 46 is `$.post('momento/newComment',`

Comment: Try removing your entire `function(data) { ... }` delegate in the call to post and see if the problem persists. Seems to be some problem with the arguments to the post function..

Comment: @AndersHolmström Completely removed `function` code was simply `$.post('momento/newComment',
                        {'picaid':currentFid,'msg':message}
                );` but the same problem reproduced. Not even posted to the server.

Comment: Hmm. What if you send some dummy data, like just a simple string?

Comment: @AndersHolmström Finally it worked in simplest form `$.post('momento/newComment');`. Thanks, PRobably I need to log my variables. Will get back after printing variables.

Comment: @AndersHolmström `console.log('currentFid='+currentFid+",message="+message);` logged `currentFid=[object Object],message=kap`. currentFid is the issue. My Bad. Sorry to create unnecessary noise.

Comment: @AndersHolmström Thanks for your time. Pls add comments summary as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm just glad we got to the problem... confusing sometimes. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments above:

It seems this was a simple case of an illegal variable supplied to the JSON data... with a pretty extensive error message.

Comment: any elaboration in this answer? this doesn't help future visitors at all.